# Verb particle noun or verb noun particle: to leave out

Tags: verbs, nouns, word-order, phrasal-verbs

Which sentence is grammatically correct or sounds more native-like?

1. Politicians tend to discuss their sources of income nontransparently, leaving the discussions surrounding them out.
2. Politicians tend to discuss their sources of income nontransparently, leaving out the discussions surrounding them.

Comment: Neither is incorrect, but the inseparable variant (2) is far more idiomatic. This is usually the case with optionally separable multi word verbs and weighty objects.

Comment: Note that a Google Ngrams search for [nontransparently,opaquely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nontransparently%2Copaquely&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows almost zero occurrences for 'nontransparently'.

Comment: Note that the phrasal verb _leave out_ **does** undergo particle shift with a pronoun direct object: _They left it out_, but not  *_They left out it_. Full noun phrases can swing both ways, as noted, but pronoun objects must precede the particle.

Comment: @JohnLawler Phrasal verb? Surely the verb is not "leave out" but just "leave". The particle "out" is a separate item, a preposition functioning as complement of "leave".

Comment: Googling, it seems that the most common word order depends on the exact meaning of *leave out.* "I accidentally left the milk out," — I didn't put it back in the refrigerator.  "I accidentally left out the milk," — I forgot to put it in the grocery order this week. (But having said that, I found both word orders associated with either of the two meanings.)

Comment: @BillJ - Yes, phrasal verb. You should use your favorite terminology and I should use mine, since there's no "surely" one can posit about grammatical terminology.  Different people have different English grammars, and many of them contain phrasal verb structures. Sorry about that.

Comment: @JohnLawler One of my main objections to the term 'phrasal verb' is that it implies that somehow the two words "leave" and "out" form a syntactic unit at word level. But "leave out" is not a constituent at word level: it’s part of the VP.  Verb is a word category, like noun, adjective, etc., and it’s "leave" that is a verb: this is the word that takes verbal inflections. So we have "They left out the discussions ...", but not *"They leave outed the discussions ...".

Comment: @BillJ Your objections, like your preferences, are your problem. I'm not interested in them, nor in terminological warfare.

Comment: @JohnLawler GGEL gives several solid reasons for rejecting the term. Surely as a grammarian, you're open-minded enough to at least read the relative section? Perhaps not.

Comment: @BillJ: CGEL, although its decisions are generally quite good, makes a number of really strange decisions. This is one of them — if they had used *phrasal verb* for separable constructions like *leave out* and *prepositional verb* for inseparable constructions like *look after* (the way ESL courses do in some languages) this would actually have made the terminology clearer. But now, they're using *prepositional verb* for both constructions, and don't have any easy way of distinguishing them.

Comment: CGEL rejects the term 'phrasal verb' because it implies that the combination of verb + preposition forms a syntactic construction belonging to the category verb, which is obviously not the case. The term 'prepositional verb' is used for those verbs that select a PP containing a specified preposition, whether or not the verb in question has a particle between it and its direct object.